# Выполнение функции по ссылке

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли сделать в Javascript так, чтобы если я перешел по ссылке (например *ru.ru/?javascript:myfunc()* ) и выполнилась бы функция *myfunc()*?

Comment: Сделайте. Кто вам мешает распарсить url и сделать eval (например)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать такой способ передачи информации своему сайту, то вам достаточно забрать параметры, то есть все после символа `?`. Вам необязательно ставить скобки, обозначающие вызов функции, достаточно имя. Широко используемый шаблон состоит в том, чтобы передать параметр `?callback={имя_вашей_функции}` и вызвать ее, используя объект `window` => `window[имя_вашей_функции]()`. Поскольку вы используете объект `window`, нужно быть уверенным, что функция объявлена глобально.